# How to keep bluetooth speakers turned on while paying music from a PC?

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, audio-streaming

How do I keep my Bluetooth speakers (JBL SB200) turned on while playing music (Spotify) from a PC running Windows 8?

They keep turning off after about 15 minutes. However, they work fine (don't turn off) when playing music through Bluetooth with my phone.

Bluetooth NIC: Qualcomm Atheros Communications

PC: Acer Aspire 7600U

Comment: Brand of Bluetooth speakers and also your motherboard brand/model could be potentially helpful.

Comment: So they just turn off abruptly while playing music from your PC? Are you sure your PC is not breaking the link (perhaps the BT NIC is switching to a power-saving mode), thus causing the speakers to turn off after a while to in turn save power since they're not being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was causing the problem! I had my other computer setup with this speaker as well but I was not using it while I was testing bluetooth with the new computer. But apparently it was taking control of the speakers every now and then anyway so that was why it kept stop playing after a while. With the other computer turned off it worked fine...